# Read Wpa_Supplicant.conf file in Android device

Tags: android

How to read `data/misc/wifi/wpa_supplicant.conf` file from android device programmatically and display it in `Textview`.

We tried below code to get root access:

```
Process psProc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"su","-c"});
FileInputStream fin = openFileInput("/data/misc/wifi/wpa_supplicant.conf");
int c;
String temp="";
while( (c = fin.read()) != -1) {
    temp += Character.toString((char)c);
}
textview.setText(temp);
//string temp contains all the data of the file.
fin.close();
```

but, we didn't get any output.

Thanks,
rama

Comment: Is not related with your problem, but `temp += temp + Character.toString((char)c);` seems strange to me: would not prefer `temp += Character.toString((char)c);` or `temp = temp + Character.toString((char)c);`?

Answer (score 0):

You can not access it without rooting your phone, you would need to grant root level permissions,

Comment: Thank u for reply. can u please tell me how to grant root level permissions.

Comment: you can't give directly but you do it by some certain steps are their so you have to follow them and get root level access  so it does void your warranty and you can replace your os also with new one.